# Exporting key value pairs from a dict based on conditionals of values for specific keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to filter key value pairs from a dictionary of dictionaries based on the value of a specific key in the nested dictionary. This is the code I have so far:

```
current_sheet = {}
four_feet_wide = []


for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    if i >= 1:
        part,height,width,sq,weight,wide,laps = sheet.row_values(i)
        current_sheet[part] = {
        'Max Height':height,
        'Max Width':width,
        'Laps':laps
        }

    for k,v in current_sheet.items(): 
        if width == 4.00:
            four_feet_wide.append(part)


pprint.pprint(current_sheet)
print(four_feet_wide)
```

This is the dict of dicts:

```
{'WLI-1-201': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 8.2, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-1-202': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 8.83, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-1-203': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 9.47, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-1-204': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 2.0, 'Max Width': 3.43},
 'WLI-2-205': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 2.0, 'Max Width': 3.33},
 'WLI-2-206': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 10.0, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-2-207': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 10.0, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-2-208': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 10.0, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-2-209': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 2.0, 'Max Width': 3.33},
 'WLI-3-210': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 2.0, 'Max Width': 3.44},
 'WLI-3-211': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 9.47, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-3-212': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 8.83, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-3-213': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 8.19, 'Max Width': 4.0}}
```

This is what it outputs:

```
['WLI-1-201', 'WLI-1-202', 'WLI-1-202', 'WLI-1-203', 'WLI-1-203', 'WLI-1-203', 'WLI-2-206',  

'WLI-2-207', 'WLI-2-207', 'WLI-2-207', 'WLI-2-207', 'WLI-2-207', 'WLI-2-208', 'WLI-2-208', 

'WLI-2-208', 'WLI-2-208', 'WLI-2-208', 'WLI-2-208', 'WLI-2-208', 'WLI-2-208', 'WLI-3-211', 

'WLI-3-211', 'WLI-3-211', 'WLI-3-211', 'WLI-3-211', 'WLI-3-211', 'WLI-3-211', 'WLI-3-211', 

'WLI-3-211', 'WLI-3-211', 'WLI-3-211', 'WLI-3-212', 'WLI-3-212', 'WLI-3-212', 'WLI-3-212', 

'WLI-3-212', 'WLI-3-212', 'WLI-3-212', 'WLI-3-212', 'WLI-3-212', 'WLI-3-212', 'WLI-3-212', 

'WLI-3-212', 'WLI-3-213', 'WLI-3-213', 'WLI-3-213', 'WLI-3-213', 'WLI-3-213', 'WLI-3-213', 

'WLI-3-213', 'WLI-3-213', 'WLI-3-213', 'WLI-3-213', 'WLI-3-213', 'WLI-3-213', 'WLI-3-213']
```

The correct keys are exported to the list, but how can I eliminate the repeats and also export the values for each key that meets the condition

Comment: Are you looking for only the values having 'Max Width' == 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas if allowed:

```
>>> d= {'WLI-1-201': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 8.2, 'Max Width': 4.0},
...  'WLI-1-202': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 8.83, 'Max Width': 4.0},
...  'WLI-1-203': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 9.47, 'Max Width': 4.0},
...  'WLI-1-204': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 2.0, 'Max Width': 3.43},
...  'WLI-2-205': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 2.0, 'Max Width': 3.33},
...  'WLI-2-206': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 10.0, 'Max Width': 4.0},
...  'WLI-2-207': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 10.0, 'Max Width': 4.0},
...  'WLI-2-208': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 10.0, 'Max Width': 4.0},
...  'WLI-2-209': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 2.0, 'Max Width': 3.33},
...  'WLI-3-210': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 2.0, 'Max Width': 3.44},
...  'WLI-3-211': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 9.47, 'Max Width': 4.0},
...  'WLI-3-212': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 8.83, 'Max Width': 4.0},
...  'WLI-3-213': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 8.19, 'Max Width': 4.0}}
...
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d).T
>>> 
>>> print(df)
           Laps  Max Height  Max Width
WLI-1-201   1.0        8.20       4.00
WLI-1-202   2.0        8.83       4.00
WLI-1-203   2.0        9.47       4.00
WLI-1-204   1.0        2.00       3.43
WLI-2-205   1.0        2.00       3.33
WLI-2-206   2.0       10.00       4.00
WLI-2-207   2.0       10.00       4.00
WLI-2-208   2.0       10.00       4.00
WLI-2-209   1.0        2.00       3.33
WLI-3-210   1.0        2.00       3.44
WLI-3-211   2.0        9.47       4.00
WLI-3-212   2.0        8.83       4.00
WLI-3-213   1.0        8.19       4.00
>>> 
>>> 
>>> v1 = df[df['Max Width'] == 4.00]
>>> print(v1)
           Laps  Max Height  Max Width
WLI-1-201   1.0        8.20        4.0
WLI-1-202   2.0        8.83        4.0
WLI-1-203   2.0        9.47        4.0
WLI-2-206   2.0       10.00        4.0
WLI-2-207   2.0       10.00        4.0
WLI-2-208   2.0       10.00        4.0
WLI-3-211   2.0        9.47        4.0
WLI-3-212   2.0        8.83        4.0
WLI-3-213   1.0        8.19        4.0
>>>
```

To get the list of keys:

```
>>> print(v1.index.to_list())
['WLI-1-201', 'WLI-1-202', 'WLI-1-203', 'WLI-2-206', 'WLI-2-207', 'WLI-2-208', 'WLI-3-211', 'WLI-3-212', 'WLI-3-213']
```

To get key-value pairs:

```
>>> print(v1.T.to_dict())  # to_dict() converts dataframe back to dictionary
{'WLI-1-201': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 8.2, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-1-202': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 8.83, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-1-203': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 9.47, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-2-206': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 10.0, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-2-207': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 10.0, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-2-208': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 10.0, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-3-211': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 9.47, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-3-212': {'Laps': 2.0, 'Max Height': 8.83, 'Max Width': 4.0},
 'WLI-3-213': {'Laps': 1.0, 'Max Height': 8.19, 'Max Width': 4.0}}
```

Comment: Liked this answer... just wanted to say you could also use `print(list(v1.T.values()))` here to get only values as the final output.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Set to eliminate duplicates
four_feet_wide = set(four_feet_wide)
# Get values for each key in the set
values = [current_sheet[k] for k in four_feet_wide] # or
values = list(current_sheet.values())

print(values)
```

You can also initialize four_feet_wide as a set so it doesn't add duplicates:

```
four_feet_wide = set()
...
four_feet_wide.add(part)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# suppose your dict of dict is stored in variable d
four_feet_wide=[]
for key,value in d.items():
    # put condition here
    if value['Max Width'] ==4.0:
        # adding filtered value to the list
        four_feet_wide.append(key)
        # printing values of dictionary along with key which matches criteria
        print(key,value)
```

In one line above code can be written as below

```
four_feet_wide = [key for key,value in d.items() if value['Max Width']==4.0]
print(four_feet_wide)
```